# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy in REACT APP

Tags: reactjs, caching, service-worker, lighthouse

Lighthouse suggests the following:
"Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy".

But how can i add a cache policy in React app? I've used create-react-app but no serviceworker was authomatically created.
How can i tackle this?

Answer (score 2):

That should be done in the settings of your web server, not the React app. For example, if you are using `nginx`, see https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-caching. Or if you are using `express` see http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/serve-static.html.